# docker-compose up -d does not create volumes while docker-compose up does

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

Is this expected behavior or a bug?

While running `docker-compose up`, my volumes are created on my local machine. But when running `docker-compose -d` up, they are not.

This is the part in the docker-compose file that's causing problems:

```
test-mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: test-mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
      - MYSQL_USER=test
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - ../www/data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

So when running `docker-compose up` for the first time, the ../www/data/mysql folder gets created.

But, If I try this with `docker-compose up -d`, the folder does not get created.

Comment: So you are deleting the folder manually before testing? Also which version of `docker` and `docker-compose`

Answer (score 3):

*docker-compose up* command will pull mysql image when you will run docker-compose up first time, next time it will use the same image , which is now saved locally.

So docker-compose up with or without -d will create the folder www , try doing it with -d first , it will create www folder.

*-d options just process your request in background.*

Hope it will help!